# Select Query returns NULL if subquery fails in the from Clause

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have two tables trans_transaction and opening_balances.
The transactions are to be inserted in the trans_transaction table. 
I need to fetch the opening_balance, closing_balance from the trans_transaction table. The opening_balances table is used for the first time when there is no transaction for the account in the trans_transaction table.
I've also written a query but the query fails if there is no record in the trans_transaction table and fails to take the data from the opening_balances table

```
SELECT `aasr`.`account_id`, `aasr`.`sub_account_id`, `aasr`.`opening_balance` `oob`, `aasr`.`shadow_opening_balance` `osb`, `aasr`.`lein_opening_balance` `olb`, `tt`.`opening_balance` `ob`, `tt`.`closing_balance` `cb`, `tt`.`shadow_balance` `sb`, `tt`.`lein_balance` `lb`
FROM `accnt_acc_subacc_rel` `aasr`,
    (
        SELECT `tti`.`transaction_id`, `tti`.`accounts_id`, `tti`.`sub_account_id`, `tti`.`opening_balance`, `tti`.`closing_balance`, `tti`.`shadow_balance`, `tti`.`lein_balance`
        FROM `trans_transaction` `tti`
        WHERE `tti`.`accounts_id` = 10 AND `tti`.`sub_account_id` = 20 AND `tti`.`effective_date` <= '2014-10-12 23:59:59'
        ORDER BY `tti`.`effective_date` DESC, `tti`.`transaction_id` DESC
    ) `tt`
WHERE `aasr`.`account_id` = 10 AND `aasr`.`sub_account_id` = 20
LIMIT 1
```

I've also tried to use the following query, but still it fails if SubQuery returns 0 rows

```
SELECT  `aasr`.`account_id`, `aasr`.`sub_account_id`,
            IF(`tt`.`opening_balance` = '', `aasr`.`opening_balance`, `tt`.`opening_balance`) AS `opening_balance`,
            IF(`tt`.`closing_balance` = '', `aasr`.`opening_balance`, `tt`.`closing_balance`) AS `closing_balance`,
            IF(`tt`.`shadow_balance` = '', `aasr`.`shadow_opening_balance`, `tt`.`opening_balance`) AS `shadow_balance`,
            IF(`tt`.`lein_balance` = '', `aasr`.`lein_opening_balance`, `tt`.`lein_balance`) AS `lein_balance`
    FROM `accnt_acc_subacc_rel` `aasr`,
        (
            SELECT `tti`.`transaction_id`, `tti`.`accounts_id`, `tti`.`sub_account_id`, `tti`.`opening_balance`, `tti`.`closing_balance`, `tti`.`shadow_balance`, `tti`.`lein_balance`
            FROM `trans_transaction` `tti`
            WHERE `tti`.`accounts_id` = 10 AND `tti`.`sub_account_id` = 20 AND `tti`.`effective_date` <= '2014-10-12 23:59:59'
            ORDER BY `tti`.`effective_date` DESC, `tti`.`transaction_id` DESC
            LIMIT 1
        ) `tt`
    WHERE `aasr`.`account_id` = 10 AND `aasr`.`sub_account_id` = 20
```

I'm not getting what's going wrong...

Comment: You've got an implicit CROSS JOIN, but CROSS JOIN anything with NULL and you only get NULLS.  You need to use a LEFT OUTER JOIN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use "LEFT OUTER JOIN" as @BaconBits advised and IFNULL:

```
SELECT  `aasr`.`account_id`, `aasr`.`sub_account_id`,
        IFNULL(`tt`.`opening_balance`, `aasr`.`opening_balance`) AS `opening_balance`,
        IFNULL(`tt`.`closing_balance`, `aasr`.`opening_balance`) AS `closing_balance`,
        IFNULL(`tt`.`shadow_balance`, `aasr`.`shadow_opening_balance`) AS `shadow_balance`,
        IFNULL(`tt`.`lein_balance`, `aasr`.`lein_opening_balance`) AS `lein_balance`
FROM `accnt_acc_subacc_rel` `aasr`
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
        SELECT `tti`.`transaction_id`, `tti`.`accounts_id`, `tti`.`sub_account_id`, `tti`.`opening_balance`, `tti`.`closing_balance`, `tti`.`shadow_balance`, `tti`.`lein_balance`
        FROM `trans_transaction` `tti`
        WHERE `tti`.`accounts_id` = 10 AND `tti`.`sub_account_id` = 20 AND `tti`.`effective_date` <= '2014-10-12 23:59:59'
        ORDER BY `tti`.`effective_date` DESC, `tti`.`transaction_id` DESC
        LIMIT 1
    ) `tt` 
    ON `aasr`.`accounts_id` = `tt`.`accounts_id` AND `aasr`.`sub_account_id` = `tt`.`sub_account_id` 
WHERE `aasr`.`account_id` = 10 AND `aasr`.`sub_account_id` = 20
```

(@Nikhilesh_Manurkar asked in comments if you could do it without a sub-query,so:)

Doing it without a sub-query (careful!!! with these WHERE conditions, it's more efficient to filter `trans_transaction` first in the sub-query):

```
SELECT  
    `aasr`.`account_id`,
    `aasr`.`sub_account_id`,
    IFNULL(`tt`.`opening_balance`, `aasr`.`opening_balance`) AS `opening_balance`,
    IFNULL(`tt`.`closing_balance`, `aasr`.`opening_balance`) AS `closing_balance`,
    IFNULL(`tt`.`shadow_balance`, `aasr`.`shadow_opening_balance`) AS `shadow_balance`,
    IFNULL(`tt`.`lein_balance`, `aasr`.`lein_opening_balance`) AS `lein_balance`

FROM 
    `accnt_acc_subacc_rel` `aasr`

LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    `trans_transaction` `tt`
    ON 
        `aasr`.`accounts_id` = `tt`.`accounts_id` 
        AND `aasr`.`sub_account_id` = `tt`.`sub_account_id` 

WHERE 
    `aasr`.`account_id` = 10 
    AND `aasr`.`sub_account_id` = 20 
    # case no record in `tt` to match `aasr` join, `tt`.`effective_date` would be null,
    # so you should add this to the "WHERE" condition
    AND ( `tt`.`effective_date` <= '2014-10-12 23:59:59' OR ISNULL `tt`.`effective_date`)

ORDER BY 
    `tt`.`effective_date` DESC, `tt`.`transaction_id` DESC
```

Comment: Can you suggest... if we do this query without SubQuery... If not can you also suggest how can we do this using correlated SubQuery...

Comment: Thanks... This one worked too... Can you please also suggest how can we do the same for multiple (account_id, sub_account_id) considering that we need only one record per (account_id, sub_account_id) that comes first in the order...

Comment: It would be OK if we could add multiple (account_id, sub_account_id) in SubQuery :)

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean. 1. you want the sub-query to get you multiple (account_id, sub_account_id), but only distinct(account_id, sub_account_id)? 2. same question about the main query

Comment: Can I email you the things... It will be greatfull if you could do so... Because I'm stuck up on it for a long time...

Comment: I mean to say if i run the subquery SELECT `tti`.`transaction_id`, `tti`.`accounts_id`, `tti`.`sub_account_id`, `tti`.`opening_balance`, `tti`.`closing_balance`, `tti`.`shadow_balance`, `tti`.`lein_balance` FROM `trans_transaction` `tti` WHERE (`tti`.`accounts_id`, `tti`.`sub_account_id`)=((10,20), (10,30)) AND `tti`.`effective_date`<='2014-10-12 23:59:59' ORDER BY `tti`.`effective_date` DESC, `tti`.`transaction_id` DESC.  If LIMIT 1 is not used all the transactions of the (account_id, sub_account_id) appear... If used only one row is returned. Can't use max(`tti`.`effective_date`) or GROUP BY

Comment: you can post here an email address and i'll contact you, or add an email address to your stackoverflow profile

Comment: great i've send you an email, please confirm

Comment: great got it, erase your comments about the mail to avoid spamming yourself and the stack...